# inserção em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo com php

Tags: php, query, phpmyadmin, sql-insert, localhost

Estou com problemas. tenho as tabelas `usuario` e `aluno` que são relacionadas por chave primária e estrangeira. Quero fazer uma inserção com `php` para inserir dados nas duas tabelas, sendo que o `idusuario` da tabela `usuario` deve aparecer no campo `idusuario` da tabela `aluno`. Vi uns exemplos, mas não funcionou e se alguem puder ajudar ficaria agradecido. segue as tabelas do banco, o formulario de inserção e o codigo `php` para inserir que tentei utilizar. A chave primária de `usuario` se liga ao `idUsuario` da tabela `aluno`.

```
CREATE TABLE aluno (
  idAluno int(11) NOT NULL,
  semestre int(50) NOT NULL,
  curso varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  idUsuario int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE usuario (
  idusuario int(11) NOT NULL,
  nome varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  campus varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  sexo varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  senha varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  tipoUsuario varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

O que eu já fiz até agora:

**tabela banco-aluno**

```
function insereAluno($conexao, $nome, $campus, $sexo, $email, $senha, $tipoUsuario, $semestre, $curso) {
    $query = "insert into usuario(nome, campus, sexo, email, senha, tipoUsuario) values ('{$nome}', '{$campus}', '{$sexo}', '{$email}', '{$senha}', '{$tipoUsuario}')";

    $query = "insert into aluno (semestre, curso, idUsuario) values ('{semestre}', '{curso}', (select LAST_INSERT_ID(idUsuario)))";
    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
```

**tabela adiciona-aluno**

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$campus = $_POST['campus'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$tipoUsuario = $_POST['tipoUsuario'];
$semestre = $_POST['semestre'];
$curso = $_POST['curso'];

    if(insereAluno($conexao, $nome, $campus, $sexo, $email, $senha, $tipoUsuario, $semestre, $curso)) { ?>
        <p class="alert">O Aluno <?= $nome ?>, do <?= $semestre ?> semestre foi adicionado. </p>
    <?php } else { 
    $msg = mysqli_error($conexao);
?>
    <p class="text-danger">O Aluno <?= $nome ?> não foi adicionado: <?= $msg?> </p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Você quer pergar o id do aluno inserido é isso?

Comment: eu quero realizar a inserção no banco. tipo é um formulario que tem informações divididas nas duas tabelas. ao realizar a inserção, o idusuario da tabela usuario tem q ser o mesmo idusuario da tabela aluno.

Comment: No topo da pergunta tem dois links com a solução do problema, é a mesma dúvida. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida pode notificar um usuário usando uma arroba antes do nome ex: @rray.